# How can I use Pattern and Matcher classes to split up a conversation in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex, loops

I've got this string which basically contains a conversation, and I want to "filter" out 1 person's text with the Pattern class.

The conversation looks like this:

```
Jack: Hi
John: Hello
Jack: How are you?
John: I'm cool, how 'bout you?
Jack: I'm cool too.
```

I am trying to put every **different** line in a different string/different array.

So I wrote this method:

```
private String getFrom(String in, String type) {
    String patr = "", Return = "";
    if (type == "title") {
        patr = "Jack:";
    }

    Pattern patr = Pattern.compile(patr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        Return = main.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    }

    if (type == "title") {
        Return = Return.substring(0, Return.length());
    }
    return Return;
}
```

The code results in:

```
String someteststring = "Jack: HiJack: How are you?Jack: I'm cool too."
```

However, I don't want this, I want every found pattern to be put in a single different string, like this:

```
someteststring[0] = "Jack: Hi"
someteststring[1] = "Jack: How are you?"
someteststring[2] = "Jack: I'm cool too."
```

I hope this explains it, can anyone help?

Comment: You don't use `==` to compare the contents of objects in Java. You need to use `String.equals()`. Also, variable names should not start with uppercase. You also seem to be ... trying to re-use the same variable name for different things ... this code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: You proably mean `if ("title".equals(type))`, not `==`.

Comment: @Guillaume - Sure, if they're all *string literals* and happen to be interned. What happens if one of his `String` objects came from a `StringBuilder`? You should *never* use `==` unless you're explicitly trying to compare reference values or primatives.

Comment: I realised that after I wrote, and deleted my comment :) You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] finalText = somteststring.split("\n");
```